# Create an independent user schema and also embed it in a message schema with Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have both a User schema and a Message schema that are currently separate, but should be related.

```
var schemaUser = new Schema({
    username: String,
    encryptPass: String,
    created: Date
});

var schemaMessage = new Schema({
    from: String,
    to: [String],
    message: String,
    created: Date
});
```

Can the User schema be created independently of the Message schema, but then be embedded in an array within a 'to:' field of the Message schema?

```
var schemaMessage = new Schema({
    from: String,
    to: [schemaUser],
    message: String,
    created: Date
});
```

From there, could each embedded user doc in the 'to:' field have a different embedded doc of 'views:' and other fields related to each user of each message?

**Does this represent different 'view' and 'read' criteria for multiple embedded users**:

```
var schemaMessage = new Schema({
    from: String,
    to: [
                {
                    schemaUser
                },
                {
                    view: {
                        inbox: Boolean,
                        outbox: Boolean,
                        archive: Boolean
                    }
                },
                {
                    read: {
                        marked: Boolean,
                        datetime: Date
                    },
                }
            ],
    message: String,
    created: Date
});
```

Comment: Your second listing is perfectly valid. Not sure what you are getting at with the third listing though, which is not valid. Why would those parts be part of a "to" field? Surely they would be properties of the message or something else.

Comment: @NeilLunn for the third, there may be multiple users in the to: field, and each user may have categorized the message differently (inbox/archive/trash..etc.), each user has marked the message read at a different point in time.. How would these factors be best represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something that basically abstracts the "User" with some custom attributes that are specific to this user's status on the message:

```
var schemaUser = new Schema({
    username: String,
    encryptPass: String,
    created: Date
});

var schemaUserMessage = new Schema({
    user: { "type": Schema.ObjectId, "ref": "User" }
    username: String,
    view: {
        inbox: Boolean,
        outbox: Boolean,
        archive: Boolean
    },
    read: {
        marked: { "type": Boolean, default: false },
        date: Date
    }
}); 

var schemaMessage = new Schema({
    from: String,
    to: [schemaUserMessage],
    message: String,
    created: Date
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );
var Message = mongoose.model( "Message", messageSchema );
```

So that intermediate schema definition which is still embedded has the information for the properties that relate to their particular "view" of the data as well as keeping some information on the appropriate user.

The "username" makes sense to keep embedded in this context as you will frequently use that and do not otherwise want to populate from an external model. But the "whole" user object, which may in fact have more fields on it than shown, does really not make much sense to embed every time.

You still keep the reference so if you need to pull up more detail, the information can easily be referenced from the `_id` that will be kept against "user" for the foreign schema.

Also, all of those properties are correctly defined as members of an array element per user in the "to" section, which is really what you want.

Comment: Very, very cool. Really appreciate all of the answers as of lately.. Truly thankful,